# access isnull combo value

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I am trying to check if there is a value selected for the combo but the true part (no value is selected) is throwing an error stating that: `There is an invalid use of the . (dot) or ! operator or invalid parentheses.`

```
If (Len(MinCombo) = 0) Then
    MsgBox "true"
Else
    MsgBox "false"
End If
```

I have also tried this code but it evaluates to the false part when a value is selected:

```
If (IsNull(MinCombo) = True) Then
    MsgBox "true"
Else
    MsgBox "false"
End If
```

I am using MS Access Professional Plus 2010

Comment: I just checked `If Me.MinCombo.Value = vbNullString Then...` and it was successful.

Comment: It still shows the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went this way:

```
Me.MinCombo.SetFocus
If (Me.MinCombo.selText ="") Then
  MsgBox "true"
Else
  MsgBox "false"
End If
```